# Reverse for 'edit' with arguments '(12,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit$']

Tags: python, html, django

**In views.py**

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "GET":    
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')
        allpost = True

        paginator = Paginator(posts, 5) # Show 5 posts per page.

        page_number = request.GET.get('page')
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

        return render(request, "network/index.html",{
            "AllPost" : allpost,
            "page_obj" : page_obj,
        })

def edit(request,post_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        content = request.POST["textarea"]
        post.content = content
        post.save()

    return redirect("index")
```

**In urls.py**

```
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("edit",views.edit,name="edit"),
```

**Index.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'edit' post.id %}" id="edit-form{{post.id}}" style="display:none;">
{% csrf_token %}
{{post.date}}
<textarea rows="5" class="form-control" name="textarea">{{post.content}}</textarea>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="float: right;">Save</button>
</form>
```

Trying to edit some post but getting an error of **Reverse for 'edit' with arguments '(12,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit$']**

Comment: The definition of `edit` in urls.py does not take any arguments, but you're calling it with an argument.

Comment: Oh..Got it!!Such a silly mistake. Thank You

Comment: Your url.py for edit is not accepting arguments, and you are calling it with one (id).

Comment: Thank You so much for correcting me!! I got it.